# php/html table structure not working as I want it to

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a table of which it is pulling information from a database. Its suppose to list the module name and then how many assignments are in it. There are two database tables involved, one simply is an id and modulename, other is id, assignment, topic, content, etc. For some reason my table won't appear correctly, it just continues rather than starting on a new line for that table. here's a picture of what it is doing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EEZo.png)

here's the code(if more is needed let me know):

```
    <div id="module_1" class="row CourseModule">
            <a href="#" onclick="showAssignments(1);">
                <div class="col-lg-12 columnPad">
                    <h1-1 class="lead">List of Modules</h1-1>
                    </a>
                    <div class="pullright">
                        <a id="addAssignmentbutton_1" class="btn btn-primary ThemeButton" href="#" onclick="addAssignment(1);"> Add Assignment</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
<div id="module_Assignments_1" class="row CanvasPad" style="display:none;">
            <table class="CanvasTable">
                <thead>
                    <th>
                         Module
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Assignments
                    </th>
                </thead>
                <?php 
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $count = 0; 
                        $query = "SELECT module_id FROM module_records";
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                        if(!$result2){
                            echo "Can't retrieve data " . mysqli_error($con);
                            exit;
                        }
                        while ($modInassignment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                            if($modInassignment['module_id'] == $row['module_id']){
                                $count++;
                            }
                        }
                ?>
                <td>
                    <a href="assignmentpermodule.php?modid=<?php echo $row['module_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['module_name']; ?></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="badge"><?php echo $count; ?></span>
                </td>
                <?php } ?>
                
                    <a href="module.php">List all assignments</a>
                
            </table>
        </div>

.js
function showAssignments(module_id){
    var html_id = "#module_Assignments_" + module_id;
    if($(html_id).css("display") == 'block'){
        $(html_id).css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $(html_id).css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a table row `tr` and then the table data `td` in it

Also, not required but good for grouping without adding divs/class/id; add all these `tr` inside a `tbody` if needed. [Read more why it's not required here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#element-restrictions)

```
<table class="CanvasTable">
    <thead>
        <th>
            Module
        </th>
        <th>
            Assignments
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $count = 0; 
                $query = "SELECT module_id FROM module_records";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                if(!$result2){
                    echo "Can't retrieve data " . mysqli_error($con);
                    exit;
                }
                while ($modInassignment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                    if($modInassignment['module_id'] == $row['module_id']){
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="assignmentpermodule.php?modid=<?php echo $row['module_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['module_name']; ?></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="badge"><?php echo $count; ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        
    </tbody>
    <a href="module.php">List all assignments</a>
</table>
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr